# How to call a .net method in AJAX on fileupload change?

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, ajax

I'm trying to upload a file using AJAX the problem is I'm a rookie in .net and don't know if I did this right or not so I appreciate any help or suggestions.

here is my html code:

```
<asp:FileUpload ID="FileUpload1" onChange="Show()" runat="server" />
```

My method should be called when users selects their file

this is the script I found in MSDN:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function Show() {
        var file = document.getElementById("FileUpload1");
        alert("test")
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "SendSms.aspx/StaticUpdate",
            data: '{name:"test" }',
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: OnSuccess,
            failure: function (response) {
                alert("test1");
            }
        });
    }
    function OnSuccess(response) {
        alert("test2");
    }
</script>
```

and here is my ASP method:

```
    [System.Web.Services.WebMethod]
public static void StaticUpdate()
{
    SendSms upload = new SendSms();
    upload.Upload();
}

public void Upload()
{
    string FileName = System.DateTime.Now.ToString("ddmmyyhhmmsss") + FileUpload1.FileName;
    if (IsPostBack)
    {
        Boolean fileOK = false;
        String path = Server.MapPath("~/Upload/");
        if (FileUpload1.HasFile)
        {
            String fileExtension =
                System.IO.Path.GetExtension(FileName).ToLower();
            String[] allowedExtensions = { ".txt" };
            for (int i = 0; i < allowedExtensions.Length; i++)
            {
                if (fileExtension == allowedExtensions[i])
                {
                    fileOK = true;
                }
            }
        }
        if (fileOK)
        {
            try
            {
                FileUpload1.PostedFile.SaveAs(path
                    + FileName);
                System.IO.StreamReader myFile =
new System.IO.StreamReader("C:\\inetpub\\wwwroot\\Viber_Bulk_UI\\Upload\\" + FileName + "");
                TextBox2.Text = myFile.ReadToEnd();
                myFile.Close();
                string Path = "C:\\inetpub\\wwwroot\\Viber_Bulk_UI\\Upload\\" + FileName + "";
                System.IO.File.Delete(Path);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Label1.Text = "File could not be uploaded.";
            }
        }
        else
        {
            Label1.Text = "Cannot accept files of this type.";
        }
    }

}
```

The error I get is this:

> NullReferenceException was unhandled by user code.
>   Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Set a breakpoint in your method and step through it when it gets called. One of the objects you're working with probably isn't properly initialized. (And that error is saying it could be any one of them) Click in the left margin by the line numbers to turn on a breakpoint, and then as it executes use F10 to step through it.

Comment: Typo? `onchange="ShowCurrentTim()"`

Comment: @Tim its not the problem

Answer (score 0):

```
 string filename = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(FileUpload1.FileName);
 string ext = System.IO.Path.GetExtension(FileUpload1.FileName);
 if (fileExtension == ".txt"){

           using (System.IO.FileStream fs = new System.IO.FileStream(Server.MapPath(("C:\\inetpub\\wwwroot\\Viber_Bulk_UI\\Upload\\" + FileName), System.IO.FileMode.Append, System.IO.FileAccess.Write, System.IO.FileShare.Read, 8, System.IO.FileOptions.None))
        {
            byte[] data = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(FileName);
            fs.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
            fs.Flush();
            fs.Close();
        }
  }
```